# Is there a non-blocking way to check if an asyncio subprocess is alive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-asyncio

When using `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec` an `asyncio.subprocess.process` is returned.  The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.asyncio.subprocess.Process) indicates that no `poll` or `is_alive` type methods exist.  It seems `wait` or `communicate` offer the only way see if a process is running, but they are blocking calls and the asyncio version of communicate does not have the timeout option.

Is there there a good way to check if an **asyncio** subprocess is alive in a **non-blocking** way?

The best I can come up with for an `is_alive` style function is:

```
import asyncio

async def is_alive(proc):
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(proc.wait(), 0.001)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Dummy use case:

```
async def foo():
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('sleep', '5')
    i = 0
    res = True
    while res:
        res = await is_alive(proc)
        print(f"[{i}] is_alive: {res}")
        # ... do foo stuff while we wait ...
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        i += 1

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(foo())
```

Output:

```
[0] is_alive: True
[1] is_alive: True
[2] is_alive: True
[3] is_alive: True
[4] is_alive: True
[5] is_alive: False
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check the `.returncode` property (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.asyncio.subprocess.Process.returncode) which will be `None` if the process is running (note that `0` indicates it has exitted, so simple truthiness checks won't work).

You should avoid polling if you can, rather, create a future, launch a task that awaits for `.wait()` and then cancels your background task.

Comment: Looks like that is what I was searching for, bit missed in the documentation fine print.